# ¿Cómo usar una variable como nombre de tabla dentro de un stored procedure de sql server

Tags: sql-server, variables, stored-procedure, tablas, tabla-dinámica

Buen día a todos, me gustaría saber ¿cómo usar una variable como nombre de tabla dentro de un stored procedure de sql server que recibe una tabla y un nombre?

Tengo esto en mi código dentro de sql server:

````
$CREATE PROCEDURE DBO.sp_TablasyNombre
@TabBack AS [DBO].TabBack READONLY,
@ArchivoNombre VARCHAR(55)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT *
INTO @ArchivoNombre --Aquí me dice que espera un Id o Quite_Id
FROM @TabBack
END```


    Lo de Arriba lo tengo que adaptar a una sentencia dinámica y me dice que debo declarar la variable
```@TabBack``` y si le pongo Quotename a la variable ```@ArchivoNombre``` me marca error y dice qué debo declarar la variable ```@TabBack``` como scalar

--El código dinámico

    
    introducir el código aquí
    ```CREATE PROCEDURE DBO.sp_TablayNombre
    @TabBack AS [DBO].TabBack READONLY,
    @ArchivoNombre VARCHAR(55),
    @FechaArchivo VARCHAR(20),
    @FechaSubidaArchivo VARCHAR(20),
    @ArchivoNombreComp VARCHAR(88)
    AS
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(500)
    SET @SQL = '

    

    CREATE TABLE [DBO].' + QUOTENAME(@ArchivoNombre) + '(
    [Id] INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1),
    [ArchivoNombre] [VARCHAR](255) NOT NULL,
    [FechaArchivo] DATE NOT NULL,
    [FechaSubidaArchivo] DATE NOT NULL,
    [ArchivoNombreCom] [VARCHAR](255) NOT NULL);

    INSERT INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@ArchivoNbre) + '(ArchivoNombre, FechaArchivo, FechaSubidaArchivo, ArchivoNombreComp)
    VALUES(' + @ArchivoNombre + ', ' + @FechaArchivo + ', ' + @FechaSubidaArchivo + ', ' + @ArchivoNombreComp + ');

SELECT Id = IDENTITY (INT, 1 , 1),
ArchivoNombre, FechaArchivo, FechaSubidaArchivo, ArchivoNombreComp,
Col1, Col2, ... Col38
INTO ' + @ArchivoNombreComp + '
    FROM @ArchivoNombre --Aquí me dice que debería declarar la variable como scalar
    RIGHT JOIN TabBack
    ON ' + QUOTENAME(@ArchivoNombre) + '. Id = TabBack. Id_Archivo;

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;

    END'
````

Espero me puedan ayudar para poder poner los nombre a las tablas y poder usarlos como cadenas e insertar.

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para usar una variable como nombre de tabla dentro de un procedimiento almacenado en SQL Server, necesitas construir y ejecutar dinámicamente una consulta SQL. El enfoque correcto es usar sp_executesql para ejecutar la consulta dinámica. Aquí tienes cómo puedes hacerlo:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE DBO.sp_TablayNombre
@TabBack AS [DBO].TabBack READONLY,
@ArchivoNombre VARCHAR(55)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @SQL = N'SELECT * INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@ArchivoNombre) + ' FROM [DBO].[TabBack]'

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
END
```

Comment: Santiago Trujillo Terán lo voy a validar y gracias por responder tan pronto